# Очень простой калькулятор

Tags: javascript

Создать страницу с двумя полями ввода и кнопкой. По нажатию кнопки скрипт должен вывести значение суммы введенных чисел. Значения по умолчанию для полей: 0.1 и 0.2.

Пример:
    ввод: 0.1, 0.2
    вывод: 0.3

```js
const result = document.getElementById('result');
const one = document.getElementById('one');
const two = document.getElementById('two');

document.getElementById('ok').addEventListener('click', function(){
  result.value = +one.value + +two.value;
});
```

```html
<input id="one" value="0.1">
<input id="two" value="0.2">
<br>
<button id="ok">OK</button>
<br>
<input id="result">
```

Comment: ну дак создайте, если надо. А пока что ознакомьтесь с правилами задания вопросов на данном ресурсе.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/hzdbak35/ - записал вот это вот. И странно получается, именно при сумме 0.1 + 0.2 выходит 0.300000000004 вместо 0.3. И я без понятия, почему так...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME https://jsfiddle.net/xuokt3ze/ Может так будет лучше? Поправил ваш ответ.